# Parse Cloud Code isn't finding my data

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to do some simple stuff with CloudCode on my data; I've been through all of the documentation, and followed all of the instructions, and nothing is working.

In my Data Browser, I have a class called "ChallengePostComment", that currently has 9 entries. I am trying to write a simple function that will query that table, return all values, then loop through them to perform some operations. But I can't even get it to return any data. Here is my function:

```
var ChallengePostComment = Parse.Object.extend("ChallengePostComment");

Parse.Cloud.define("generate_comment_notifications", function(request, response) {

console.log("request = " + JSON.stringify(request));
var query = new Parse.Query(ChallengePostComment);
query.find().then(function(results) {
  console.log("results = " + JSON.stringify(results));
  response.success("Completed. " + results.length + " results.");
},
function(error) {
  console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
});

});
```

As you can see, right now all it does is perform the query, log the results, and return the count of the results. But I always get 0 results.

Here is how I'm calling the function from curl:

```
curl -X POST \
     -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <my app id>" \
     -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: <my rest api key>" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{}' \
     https://api.parse.com/1/functions/generate_comment_notifications
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm about to lose my mind here.

Comment: Is anything printing to the console?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel stupid. It turns out I had a typo in my Class definition, so the name I was looking for wasn't the name that actually existed in the database. My mistake.